# Stop Winsound / Stop a thread on Python

Tags: python, multithreading, audio, tkinter

Im writing a litle game on python using Tkinter (And by the way, i am not allowed to use any other non built in modules) and I want to play a background song when on the main window, wich is the one that holds the title, and the buttons to go to other windows and stuff...

So the thing is that I need that sound to stop when I enter to another window, but when I hit the button to go, to another window, the song keeps playing...

I'm using the winsound module, and had define a couple of functions, (That by the way, are wicked as hell) to play the song when I first run the program using threads...

So here is the deal, I want something to put in the function "killsound" so that I can add it to every button, and then when I press any button to open any other window, the sound will be killed.

I was hoping something like 'a.kill()' or 'a.stop()' but it didnt worked.

And I really don´t know how to use the SND_PURGE thing on winsound... Although I understand that SND_PURGE is no longer working on new windows OS (Got Win8.1)

Could you please help me?

Thank You! (And Sorry for the creepy english...)

```
def Play(nombre): #This function Is the core of the winsound function
   ruta = os.path.join('Audio',nombre)
   Reproducir= winsound.PlaySound(ruta,winsound.SND_FILENAME)
   return Reproducir

def PlayThis(): 
   while flag_play:
       try:
           return Play('prettiest weed.wav')
       except:
           return "Error"

def PlayThisThread():
   global flag_play
   flag_play= True
   a=Thread(target=PlayThis, args=())
   a.daemon = True
   a.start()

   PlayThisThread()


def killsound():  #This is the function I want, for killing sound.
   global flag_play
   flag_play = False
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 major problems in your code:

1. global variable `flag_play` has to be placed inside the sound playback loop, in your case within the `PlayThis()` function
2. the `Winsound` module is aiming simple non-threaded usage. while the sound is playbacked, there is no chance to "softly" interrupt. It does not support any playback status reporting e.g. `.isPlaying()` nor any kind of `.stop()` that you need in order to kill it.

Solution:

- try [PyMedia](http://pymedia.org/tut/play_wav.html) package. Pymedia allows lower-level audio manipulation therefore more details have to be provided at the initialisation:

  ```
  import time, wave, pymedia.audio.sound as sound

  # little to do on the proper audio setup

  f= wave.open( 'prettiest weed.wav', 'rb' )
  sampleRate= f.getframerate() # reads framerate from the file
  channels= f.getnchannels()
  format= sound.AFMT_S16_LE  # this sets the audio format to most common WAV with 16-bit codec PCM Linear Little Endian, use either pymedia or any external utils such as FFMPEG to check / corvert audio into a proper format.
  audioBuffer = 300000  # you are able to control how much audio data is read
  ```

with the following assigment the "snd" becomes an instance of the class [sound.Output](http://pymedia.org//docs/pymedia.audio.sound.html#Output) and gives you bunch of useful audio methods:

```
    snd= sound.Output( sampleRate, channels, format )
    s= f.readframes( audioBuffer )
    snd.play( s )
```

and finally your threaded playback loop might look as follows:

```
    while snd.isPlaying():
      global flag_play
      if not flag_play: snd.stop()  #here is where the playback gets interupted.
      time.sleep( 0.05 )

    f.close()
```

Please, let me know if you need more support on this.

Comment: @shaktimaan, looks nicer, thanks for editing. Hopefuly it helps me also to gain some reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

I also created a 0.5 sec wavfile in Adobe Audition containing silence and attached it to the stop button, and this basically "stopped" playback of the previously played audio clip.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to do it, by adding a 0.5sec sound to a button, so that when I press the button it stops the background one to play the button one, and then stops all sounds on program.